# Reading multiple csv files with specific string value

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple csv files in my directory but I want to read files with specific strings in filename.

Files:

```
QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI3_2021_ListPrice.csv,
QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI4_2021_GrsToNet.csv,
QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI3_2021_UnitsChanges.csv
```

I want to read only files having "List Price" and "Units Changes" at one go.

Tried this:

```
os.chdir(path=source_path)
all_csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
print(all_csv_files)

for file in all_csv_files:
    if ("ListPrice" in file):
        uploadfiles = [f for f in listdir(source_path)
        if isfile(join(source_path, f))]
            print("Upload files:", *uploadfiles, sep='\n')
```

Comment: os.chdir(path=source_path)
all_csv_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
print(all_csv_files)
for file in all_csv_files:
    if ("ListPrice" in file):
        uploadfiles = [f for f in listdir(source_path) if isfile(join(source_path, f))]
        print("Upload files:", *uploadfiles, sep='\n')

Comment: forgot to add code...added in the comment above

Comment: [edit] your question and add your formatted code, never add code as comment. Also: [mre] && [ask]

Comment: Please don't put large amount of code in comments — put it in your question where it belongs and can be properly formatted. You also need to be much clearer about what you want to do with matching files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your specific files with this code, also you can modify all filesName **list** at one go-

```
import pandas as pd
filesName = [
    "QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI3_2021_ListPrice.csv",
    "QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI4_2021_GrsToNet.csv",
    "QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_6698_WI3_2021_UnitsChanges.csv"
]

keywords = [
    "ListPrice",
    "UnitsChanges"
]

for names in filesName:
    for key in keywords:
        if key in names:
            df = pandas.read_csv(names)
            print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this question is just about filtering a list, there are many StackOverflow posts related to ['[python] filter a list'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+filter+a+list), I recommend you check them out.

Specifically for your question, how about "glob-ing" for each kind of file and combining them:

```py
lp_files = glob.glob('*ListPrice.csv')
uc_files = glob.glob('*UnitsChanges.csv')
filtered = lp_files + uc_files
```

I think that very clearly shows you and anyone else what you want/expect.

If you still want to only glob once, and filter multiple files, I suggest creating a little filter function:

```py
def csv_filter(fname):
    if 'ListPrice' in fname:
        return True
    if 'UnitsChanges' in fname:
        return True
    # if 'SomeOtherText' in fname:
    #     return True

    return False
```

You can add and remove file names from that list very easily; just leave the final `return False` for any file that doesn't match your filters.

You can call that from a one-line list comprehension:

```py
all_csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
filtered = [x for x in all_csv_files if csv_filter(x)]
```

which is equivalent to this more traditional for-loop, which you were trying:

```py
filtered = []
for x in all_csv_files:
    if  csv_filter(x):
        filtered.append(x)

# Now, do something with filtered CSVs
# ...
```

Also, there might something else wrong here, but I'm not sure:

```py
if ("ListPrice" in file):
    uploadfiles = [f for f in listdir(source_path)
    if isfile(join(source_path, f))]
        print("Upload files:", *uploadfiles, sep='\n')
```

You have the condition that if `file` matches your `'ListPrice'` filter, do something, but you are not doing anything with `file`.  There may be some broader implication of having found a 'ListPrice' file in `source_path`, but I'd expect to see `file` used somewhere inside that if-statement.